# Multiple forms using multiple columns with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build a 2 column page posting  to 2 different actions. But the placement should be like following:

```
+----------------+ +-----------------+
|                | |                 |
|                | |  Should post to |
| Should post to | |  Form1          |
| Form1          | |                 |
|                | |                 |
|                | |                 |
|                | |                 |
|                | +-----------------+
|                | +-----------------+
|                | |Should post to   |
|                | |Form2            |
|                | |                 |
|                | |                 |
|                | |                 |
+----------------+ +-----------------+
+--------+         +------+
|Submit  |         |Submit|
|Form1   |         |Form2 |
+--------+         +------+
```

There is no form2 right now, because I couldn't manage to place it on a proper place while I am using regular bootstrap grids. How should I design the page? How should i wrap inputs and divs with form tags?

Edit: The current state is like following. As I stated, I couldn't place form2 yet..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <form action="/form1">
            <div class="col-md-6">

                <!-- bootstrap input groups for form 1 //-->

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                        <button type="submit" id="bbtn" class="btn btn-success">first form submit</button>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">@Localize("AdditionalProductInfo")</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!-- bootstrap input groups for form 1 continued.. //-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share code what you have tried to debug easily

Comment: @NagaSaiA I edited question

Comment: are you looking for something like this - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZONkKE?editors=1100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 `form` attribute to link elements to the form that are outside a form.

For the structure :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <form id="form1" class="well well-lg">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName">First Name</label>
        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="First Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputLastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="lastname" class="form-control" id="exampleInputLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="well well-lg">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" form="form1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" form="form1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <form class="well well-lg">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
        <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox">Check me out
        </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here's the [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/X7Dvj7TdNM#)**

Comment: This seems to solve problem. I am not sure of browser support though. Thanks.